# How to numerically solve this nonlinear ODE?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods

I am trying to understand the behavior of solutions for the following ODE

$$u''+\frac{2}{r}u'-\frac{K}{(1+r^2)^2}u = u^5$$

with initial conditions $u(0)=d>0$ and $u'(0)=0$. When I try numerically plot this in Python using `odeint` ([example](https://www.epythonguru.com/2020/07/second-order-differential-equation.html)), I get a division by $0$ error. I am guessing the problem arises from the term $\frac{u'}{r}$. Is there a way to get around this?

Comment: yes indeed $u(r)$

Comment: you can multiply your ode by $r$ to get rid of the division by zero. Not sure if the code you are using will take such equation. In any case, it is possible to solve this using numerical methods.

Comment: @Moo $K>0$ is a constant and $d=1.$ I am trying to understand the asymptotic behaviour of the solutions using the shooting method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the limit $r\to 0$ you get by mean value or l'Hôpital
$$
3u''(0)-Ku(0)=u(0)^5.
$$
Thus for some small interval around zero your solution reads as
$$
u(r)=d+\frac{Kd+d^5}6r^2.
$$
So start the interval at some positive smallish $h$ with initial conditions
$$
u(h)=d+\frac{Kd+d^5}{6}h^2,~~~ u'(h)=\frac{Kd+d^5}{3}h
$$
If necessary prepend the $r=0$ point to the solution arrays.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking to investigate it numerically, perhaps try making the substitution $u_1 := u$, $u_2 := \frac{du}{dr}$, from which you get the system

$$\frac{du_1}{dr} = u_2$$
$$\frac{du_2}{dr} = u_1^5 + \dfrac{K}{(1+r^2)^2}u_1 -\dfrac{2}{r}u_2$$

and then numerically solving using a Runge-Kutte method or similar approach. As mentioned by Lutz Lehmann you will have to consider the initial time step analytically via some other means due to the $1/r$ term.